# Chrome Notification visible in all tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I am writing an extension for chrome where I have to show a notification in current tab. By using below code I am able to display Notification but it is visible on all tabs. How I can make sure that Notification is visible on current tab only

```
var notification = new Notification('Notification title', {
icon: '2_Flat_logo_on_transparent_82x75.png',
   body: statusText
 }); 
notification.onclick = function () {
    window.open(url);      
 };**
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature to display a Notifcation in a single tab only in the [Notifcations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API)

However you could make it yourself with help of `window.onblur` and `window.onfocus`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
    Notification.requestPermission();
});

var delay = 0;
var realClose = false;
var currentNotifs = 0;

function createCurrentTabNotification(title, body, icon, onclick) {
  if (Notification.permission == "denied") {
    return alert("Permission denied!");
  } else if (Notification.permission == "default") {
    Notification.requestPermission();
    alert("Please allow notifications!");
    return setTimeout(function() {
      createCurrentTabNotification(title, body, icon, onclick);
    }, 5000);
  }

  function blur() {
    currentNotifs++;
    delay = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
      blurred = true;
      if (notification && !realClose) {
        notification.close();
      }
    }, 100);
  }

  function focus() {
    blurred = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
      blurred = false;
      if (notification && !realClose) {
        detach("blur", blur);
        detach("focus", focus);
        setTimeout(function() {
          createCurrentTabNotification(notification.title, notification.body, notification.icon, notification.onclick);
        }, delay);
        delay += 300;
      }
      currentNotifs--;
      if (!currentNotifs) realClose = false;
    }, 100);
  }

  var blurred = false;
  var attach = window.addEventListener;
  var detach = window.removeEventListener;

  var notification = new Notification(title, {
    body: body,
    icon: icon
  });

  notification.onshow = function() {
    if (!document.hasFocus()) {
      blurred = true;
      notification.close();
    }
  };

  notification.onclick = function() {
    notification.close();
    onclick();
  };

  notification.onclose = function() {
    if (!blurred) {
      realClose = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
        realClose = false;
      }, 111);
      if (currentNotifs > 0) currentNotifs--;
      notification = null;
      detach("blur", blur);
      detach("focus", focus);
    }
  };

  attach("blur", blur);
  attach("focus", focus);
}

function notify() {
  createCurrentTabNotification("My notification", "Hey!", null, function() {
    window.open("http://www.google.com");
  });
}
```

Check it out here: http://output.jsbin.com/voyapozice/1

Comment: @user1583888 What part isn't working? What errors do you get? I've updated my answer, now works with mutliple notifications and should work cross-browser